# How do I secure a cableless adapter to a cable to make it an optional feature?

Tags: usb, cable

We have:

- a USB-C cable
- a USB-A adapter (cableless*)

Some users will need to use the adapter, some users won't need to use it. How can I secure the USB-A adapter to the USB-C cable as an optional feature?

*cableless - because the USB-A adapter is cableless, this isn't an option: http://www.extron.com/product/product.aspx?id=lockitadaptertether&search=lockit

Comment: Get a different adapter that has a cable? Use some other kind of wire to attach it just like the product you linked? Right now this just looks like an advertisement. What USB-A adapter is it?

Comment: @Seth Sure, I may have to do that and if it works that's great. But if possible I'd like it as sleek as possible. Looks a bit messy with that solution. 

[USB-A Adapter]http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-C-Female-to-USB-3-0-Male-Port-adapter-USB-3-1-Type-C-to-USB3-0-Type-A-UK-/252469442337?hash=item3ac859f721:g:ZIAAAOSwqfNXkESK

Comment: Trying to secure that? Just buy a new adapter. You'd probably have to use glue to attach anything to it in a reasonably secure manner. Alternatively only hand out the adapter on request.

Comment: Sure it seems stupid. Maybe I should of outlined the scale of how big the user base is. I work for one of the biggest companies in the world and this is just a small task I said I'd help out with. It's potentially a solution for thousands of desks in our London space. That's why we need it secured.

Comment: @BLS93 - It sounds like a homemade solution is best.  You can always just equip the hardware that needs it with a USB Type-C PCI-e card.

Comment: While it might be a solution for thousand of desks it simply means you bought the wrong equipment. From that picture of the article the adapter is maybe 2 cm long, does have a pretty even surface and gets smaller towards one end. There are no eyelets, screw holes or any other kind of attachment points for a secure attachment. Short of gluing something to it or maybe having something that attaches to the holes of the USB connector there is no way to permanently attach something to it. Either buy new adapters with a cable to use your first solution or get your first solution and a glue gun.